# how to count different values for different keys in associative arrays using php

Tags: php

Below the code is giving a output total number of absentees and present. But my requirement, is to have a number of absentees and present, per branch.

I want output like:

```
cse-a: presnties:5 ;absenties:4
Cse-g:presenties:4 ;absenties:3
```

Below is my code:

```
 <?php
 $present = 0;
$absent = 0;
 $students = array(array('CSE-A'=>'PRESENT'),array('CSE-A'=>'PRESENT'),array('CSE-G'=>'ABSENT'),array('CSE-   G'=>'ABSENT'),array('CSE-   A'=>'ABSENSENT'),array('CSE-   G'=>'PRESENT'),array('CSE-G'=>'PRESENT'));//Sampled Array
foreach($students as $key=>$array)
{
   foreach($array as $k=>$v)
   {
    if($array[$k] === 'PRESENT')
    {
        $present++;
    }
     else if ($array[$k] === 'ABSENT')
    {
        $absent++;
    }
   }
}
  echo "Present Totals: ".$present.PHP_EOL;
   echo "Absent Totals: ".$absent;
```

Comment: WHY DO YOU THINK CAPSLOCK WILL GET YOU MORE ATTENTION?! - Edit your question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$students = [
    ['CSE-A'=>'PRESENT'],
    ['CSE-A'=>'PRESENT'],
    ['CSE-G'=>'ABSENT'],
    ['CSE-G'=>'ABSENT'],
    ['CSE-A'=>'ABSENSENT'],
    ['CSE-G'=>'PRESENT'],
    ['CSE-G'=>'PRESENT'],
];

$outputs = [];

foreach ($students as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($outputs[$key])) {
            $outputs[$key] = [
                'present' => 0,
                'absent'  => 0,
            ];

        }

        //check value
        if($array[$key] === 'PRESENT') {
            $outputs[$key]['present']++;
        } else if($array[$key] === 'ABSENT') {
            $outputs[$key]['absent']++;
        }
    }
}

foreach ($outputs as $key => $value) {
    echo $key."\n";
    echo "Present Totals: ".$value['present']."\n";
    echo "Present Totals: ".$value['absent']."\n";
    echo "--------------\n";
}
```

Comment: but iam not understanding

Comment: if (!isset($outputs[$key])) {
            $outputs[$key] = [
                'present' => 0,
                'absent'  => 0,
            ];